# In which condition CO uses the oxygen end for bonding?

Tags: coordination-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, organometallic-compounds

Generally Metal Carbonyl complex are formed from Carbon end. Is it possible under some specific condition that the Oxygen end is used?

(PS -I know about the structures of M-CO bonding)

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for: there probably are some Frustrated Lewis Pair systems with $\ce{CO}$ wherein the oxygen is coordinated. Technically, those are complexes.

Comment: Of course it's possible - there's impressive variety of modes of coordination of CO.

Comment: @Mithoron I mean under what conditions will CO be O-Coordinated